# Inconsistent behavior in PyTorch when slicing before and after using the neural network

Tags: torch

I have the following inconsistent behavior that I don't understand. In the first case, the assertion fails and in the second case, the assertion succeeds.
`batch_patches` is a batch of size `torch.Size([64, 3, 64, 64])`. `net` is a modified ResNet-152 and it produces a multivariate Gaussian distribution. `indexes` is a boolean vector.

I am only interested in the output where `indexes` elements are true. So, when I pass all patches to `net` and then I extract the wanted outputs using `indexes` it gives different results compared to first pass the wanted patches. Does anyone know what the reason is?

```
locations2 = []
locations1 = []
with torch.inference_mode():
    batch_patches = data_loader.dataset.tensors[0]
    batch_dist = net(batch_patches.to(Globals.device))
    locations2.append(batch_dist.loc.cpu()[indexes])
    dist2 = net(batch_patches[indexes].to(Globals.device))
    locations1.append(dist2.loc.cpu())
    assert torch.all(locations1[0] == locations2[0])
```

Case 2:

```
locations2 = []
locations1 = []
with torch.inference_mode():
    batch_patches = data_loader.dataset.tensors[0]
    batch_dist = net(batch_patches.to(Globals.device)[indexes])
    locations2.append(batch_dist.loc.cpu())
    dist2 = net(batch_patches[indexes].to(Globals.device))
    locations1.append(dist2.loc.cpu())
    assert torch.all(locations1[0] == locations2[0])
```